# Updating prices on subscription renewals with WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I recently updated pricing on my WooCommerce subscriptions, but the renewals are still being processed at the old prices. How do I update the prices for the renewals? Even better, is there a way to automate the updating on renewals when I make changes to the pricing? (I'm using WordPress, in case that affects answers.)

So far, I've just searched the WooCommerce setting to see if there's anything that will address my problem.